# Java StringBuffer

Tags: java, string, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I am trying to download XML document from Server. From my log I see that I am getting complete document; however, when I convert the document into String, I only have 4096 bytes.

```
private String getString(InputStream inputStream) {
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[2048];
    StringBuffer sB = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        while (true)
        {
            int i = inputStream.read(arrayOfByte);
            if (i == -1) {
               return sB.toString();
            }
            sB.append(new String(arrayOfByte, 0, i));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Can anybody give any explanation on what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't think that is your problem here, but this code is not Unicode-safe. A single character can have more than one byte and might break when it spans your buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I always use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) for this kind of stuff:

```
String stuff = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

However, your code looks okay, so the error is probably somewhere else.